# Fabric and iOS: com.apple.share.Twitter.post invalidated

Tags: ios, twitter, twitter-fabric

I'm using Fabric (TWTRComposer) to post a Tweet, where into the message I added @user, like this:

```
[composer setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%@", tmp.username]];
```

but when I try to post this message with the @user, xcode send me that

com.apple.share.Twitter.post invalidated

But when I send a message without @user, it works... How can I solve this?

Comment: Hi I got same warning! Did you find a solution?

Comment: try to check @user !=nil ?

Comment: oh...
I tried it .
I got same warning too  HAHA
But It's work ,just has error